# Split HTML in Twig conditional

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I would like to do this inside a for loop

```
{% if count % 2 == 0 %}
    <div class="col-md-6"><!--start block-->
        <div class="item-small gutter-bottom">
            <img src="{{ item.image_url }}"/>
            <div class="item-title">{{ item.name }}</div>
        </div>
{% else %}
        <div class="item-small gutter-bottom">
            <img src="{{ item.image_url }}"/>
            <div class="course-title">{{ item.name }}</div>
        </div>
    </div><!--end block-->
{% endif %}
```

where I put an additional div wrapping every two items. However, when rendered in HTML, the closing tags went all wrong and the output is not pleasant.

Comment: Would you mind adding the desired and the actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in this way (I put an own example for the loop):

```
{% for i in 0..9 %}
    {% if loop.index0 % 2 == 0 %}
    <div class="col-md-6"><!--start block-->
        <div class="item-small gutter-bottom">
            <img src="{{ item.image_url }}"/>
            <div class="item-title">{{ item.name }}</div>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="item-small gutter-bottom">
            <img src="{{ item.image_url }}"/>
            <div class="course-title">{{ item.name }}</div>
        </div>
    </div><!--end block-->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You need to take care about the indexes of the loop, because if the 'if' code is not rendered first, your rendered html wouldn't be good, and the same occurs if in the last iteration the 'else' code is not rendered.

Comment: yes, I realise it's a program error, not a bug in the template language. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad that the answer has been useful for you. I'd appreciate if you voteup the answer. Thanks and greetings.

Answer (score 3):

You should use twig's **[batch](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html)** method instead.

```
{% for row in items|batch(2) %}

    <div class="col-md-6"><!--start block-->

        {% for item in row %}

            <div class="item-small gutter-bottom">
                <img src="{{ item.image_url }}"/>
                <div class="item-title">{{ item.name }}</div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}

    </div><!--end block-->

{% endfor %}
```